# Windows Automation Tool

Tags: windows, macros

I need any tool to automate my daily work in windows with dialogs.
I've google it and found few tools, but i don't know anything about they.
Please advice me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoIT is one of the best Windows automation language's out there

It can retrieve text from active dialogs

```
  WinGetText("[CLASS:Notepad]","")
```

Perform controlled clicks on any button in a dialog

```
ControlClick($windowname, "", "[CLASS:Button; TEXT:Show Results; INSTANCE:1]")
```

The real plus about AutoIt is it's extensive documentation, (Use the F1 key ;)) and forum support

http://www.autoitscript.com/

Answer (score 2):

AutoHotKey is a really good tool for this, open source. http://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: I use AutoHotKey for KeyBoards Hotkeys, but i think it is not comfortable to use for automate big work on dialogs. Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: For "big work" something like automated UI testing I also use TestComplete - it handles custom controls and allows you to either record activities or write completely custom scripts but definitely is not free.